# Reactjs: Server side rendering with material-ui introduces lags

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I added material-ui (v0.14.4) to the mern starter boiler place and spread the useragent via muiTheme (as seen [here](https://github.com/lorix-lpan/mern-starter/blob/master/shared/App.js)). However, although no errors are logged to the console, it introduces a significant latency to all of the material-ui components. Is there a better way to configure server rendering with material-ui components without introducing lags?

You can clone this [repo](https://github.com/lorix-lpan/mern-starter/) to have a better picture on what is going on.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I could not see any component files in the repo. You can use ReactMaterial package which works well with react.

Comment: React components as well as routes are in the shared directory https://github.com/lorix-lpan/mern-starter/tree/master/shared